# Some images aren't showing up on my github pages portfolio

Tags: html, github-pages

3/8 images for my projects on my github portfolio arent showing up on github pages but do work when I open a local browser.

```
div class="cbp-item development">
                            <!-- data-title attribute will be use to populate lightbox caption -->
                            
                            <img src="assets/img/streak.png" alt="custom alt 1" class="img-fluid"></a>
                            <div class="cbp-hover">
                                <h4><a class="cbp-lightbox" data-title="Portfolio One"
                                        >Streaking</a></h4>
                                <p><a target="_blank" href="https://github.com/dodgen92/Streaking">React JS memory game</a></p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

This is a snippet of a broken image (the indentation is cleaner in the actual code), I'm quite baffled as they're all essentially a boiler plate of each other. Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure to capitalize the image's file extensions.